# Assign new user a plan upon registration in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When a new user registers, they should be automatically assigned to a plan subscription. I can do that manually in Tinker (Laravel 5):

```
  $token = Input::get('stripeToken');
  $user = User::all();
  $user->subscription('monthly')->create($token);

  flash('Your account has been created with a membership');
```

Where, in Laravel 5, do I put such logic?

**Edit**

```
public function create(array $data)
{

    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
       'company_name' => $data['company_name'],
        // I have added the below:
        $token = Input::get('stripeToken');
       $user = User::all();
       $user->subscription('loop')->create($token);
    ]);

}
```

Comment: If you are using Laravels `Registrar` service then I'd do it in there

Comment: Hi @lukasgeiter Is that inside the create function

Comment: Yes exactly. `User::create([...])` returns the user model which you can then use to create the subscription.

Comment: @lukasgeiter nothing works. User is not creating.

Comment: Please add the code that is not working to your question

Comment: @lukasgeiter I has been added

Comment: Small text improvement ... makes it easier to read the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravels `Registrar` service then I'd do it in there. That could look like this:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'company_name' => $data['company_name']
    ]);
    $token = Input::get('stripeToken');
    $user->subscription('loop')->create($token);
    return $user;
}
```

You might also want to get the `stripeToken` from the `$data` array but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Hi. It doesnt work but it creates the user and stays on a blank screen (white browser) How to take it from the $data array?

Comment: Anything in the logs? You should be able to do `$data['stripeToken']`

Comment: only `[2015-04-10 15:50:03] local.ERROR: exception 'Stripe_InvalidRequestError' with message 'Could not determine which URL to request: Laravel\Cashier\Customer instance has invalid ID:`

Comment: This seems to be a cashier problem (which I don't know) so I can't really help you. Sorry..